# How to Fix the error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am doing a tutorial, and have one problem with error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

****>> I just update the question follow your advice.
  
And added 2 line code:

```
let cell: TacoCell = collectionView.dequeReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.configureCell(taco: ds.tacoArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
```

And i also modify this code:

```
func dequeReusableCell to dequeReusableCell
```

In my UICollectionView+Ex.swift file.

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionView {
func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView {

    let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: nil)
    register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier)

}

func dequeReusableCell<T: UICollectionView>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView{
    guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? T else {
        fatalError("Coud not deque cell with Identifier: \(T.reuseIdentifier)")
    }
    return cell
}

}

extension UICollectionViewCell: ReusableView {}
```

and in my MainVC.swift, I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, DataServiceDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var headerView: HeaderView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var ds: DataService = DataService.instance

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ds.delegate = self
    ds.loadDeliciousTacoData()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    headerView.addDropShadow()
    /*
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TacoCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TacoCell")
    */
    collectionView.register(TacoCell.self)
}

func deliciousTacoDataLoaded() {
   print("Delicious Taco Data Loaded!")
}


}

extension MainVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ds.tacoArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TacoCell", for: indexPath) as? TacoCell {
//            cell.configureCell(taco: ds.tacoArray[indexPath.row])
//            return cell
//        }
//        return UICollectionViewCell()

    let cell: TacoCell = collectionView.dequeReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.configureCell(taco: ds.tacoArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 95, height: 95)
}

}
```

At this line:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as TacoCell
```

the compiler complains.

Why this error was showed, and how to fix it? Thank in advance.
  
==> After do like your advice, now i can build success.
My problem is soved. I still implement something, if have more any issue, i will update again. Many thanks!

Comment: Your generic constraint says `<T: UICollectionView>` when it should be `<T: UICollectionViewCell>`.

Comment: @totiG if you use type annotation, there's no type inference taking place, since you explicitly told the compiler what the type (you think) should be :) Type checking still takes place though, so invalid type annotations won't work.

Comment: It would be great if you can edit your question and include the least amount of related code. A lot of your code have nothing to do with the issue. That way you'll get answers faster...

Comment: @dan thank you for your help, i modified  <T: UICollectionView> to <T: UICollectionViewCell> and one issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the generic constraint for `dequeReusableCell` to be: `<T: UICollectionViewCell>` instead of `<T: UICollectionView>`:

```
func dequeReusableCell<T: UICollectionViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView{
```

Obviously, I would assume that `TacoCell` is type of `ReusableView`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the typo(s)

   ```
   func dequeueReusableCell<T: UICollectionViewCell>( ...
   ```
2. Annotate the type and remove the type cast

   ```
   let cell : TacoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath)
   ```

Comment: I don't think #2 is necessary, the compiler can infer a generic return type based on an `as` cast

Comment: @vadian Thank much because you helped my several times. Your solution is correct. My issue is solved.

Comment: @dan i tried again again and #2 is not necessary like you said. Thk you.